# Allow End User To Add To Model, Form, and Template Django

Tags: python, django

Is there anything that someone could point me towards (a package, an example, a strategy, etc) of how I could implement the ability for an end user of my app to create a new field in a model, then add that model field to a model form and template? I’m thinking of the way that Salesforce allows users to add Custom fields.

I don’t really have any start point here I am only looking to learn if/how this might be possible in Django.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for same type of solution. But with some research, I came to know that we have this using `ContentTypes` framework.

How to do it? We can utilize ContentType's `GenericForeignKeys` and `GenericRelations`.